# When you agree with a person's point but you find their way of making that point obnoxious

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Let's say you're listening in on/reading a conversation about some topic, and someone in that conversation decides to make their own point. In terms of the point they're making you can agree with them, but the way they handle expressing that point is incredibly obnoxious and off-putting. What would be a word or phrase to describe that kind of mixed reaction one would have to that?

I know that for a while there was a fake German word floating around that essentially meant what I'm getting at (i.e. Waltersobchakeit), but I'm hoping there's something already existing in language to articulate the same idea.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I find _The German term for when a person makes up a random German-sounding word out of nowhere and people believe it anyway supposedly the definition for "Waltersobchakei"_ in UD...but it is not even a word in German.

Comment: Wouldn't the term be something more like "dudism"?  It was the Dude who reacted to Walter ("You're not wrong, Walter, you're just an a------").  The Sobchakism would be *making a point, but being an a------ about it*

Comment: @Cascabel For the sake of articulating that this person is being rude in the way they present their point, I think language with a negative connotation would be needed.

Comment: Would [pejorative-language] or [insults] be included in this?

Comment: @Cascabel In terms of how the person making their point is acting, yes.

Comment: Maybe you feel *grudging respect*?